# IntelliJ "Executing pre-compile tasks...:"

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working on a large project using `IntelliJ 14.1` latest.

Recently, whenever I stop editing for a minute or so, IntelliJ freezes for several minutes with the message "`Executing pre-compile tasks...:`" followed by the message "`All files are up-to-date`".

Any idea what is causing this behavior and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Any solution to this one?

Comment: JetBrain's techncal support said that they added it to their "issues" list but they have never go back to me on this.
My company changed their network structure in November and since then the problem was greatly reduced so it appears to be network related. However, none of my colleagues had this problem at all, so there must also be a configuration component involved.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem and it drove me nuts for about 3 days. The existing answers did not solve it. Neither did deleting preferences, caches, re-installing IntelliJ on my machine helped. I even tried to turn my Mac [off and on again](https://www.cipher-it.co.uk/have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again/)

Finally, what worked for me was to delete the `.idea` folder (which is usually located in the root of project)

Of course I feel stupid. Hope this helps someone else because this is one of the top hits for those keywords.

IntelliJ version : IDEA 2019.2.3 (Community Edition) on macOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the classes folder inside target
Now try building , it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem becasue 2 things:
- In source code have `pre-compile` script.
- IntelliJ IDEA build project automaticaly when IDE is idle.

**Solution:**

- Choose menu `File \ Settings...` or press combine keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
- Choose `Build, Execution, Deployment` \ `Compiler` , uncheck item `Make project autimatically (only work while not running / debugging)`
  or type in search box at top-left corner, search keyword something like the above.

[image]

Comment: That is what I initially assumed was the problem but I checked and "Make project automatically" is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause of the problem was "Latest" setting for some library versions (Project structure - Libraries). If you see something like
"Executing pre-compile tasks… Resolving Maven library google.code.gson..." at the Build tab that is probably the case: fetching last version info for each library can take long time.